# How to do click events using jquery in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Right now I am appending a div with the class button to the body of popup.html, and then in the popup.js I am using jQuery to do an click event, but it is not working. It works when I put the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJKkW/). 
Here is the HTML that I am appending to the body:

```
<div class="button">Clear Saved Login</div>
```

Here is the jQuery that I use to try to get something to happen when it gets clicked on:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function() {
       alert('worked');
   });
});
```

I know that jQuery is being imported because if I put an alert right about the document.ready() it will alert me. I don't know if it is a chrome thing or I am missing something.

Comment: Please include the exact HTML/JS/etc you have in popup.html in the question. This will better help us identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I had to make sure I downloaded the JQuery library into a file called jquery.js that I put in the folder of my plugin.  Then in your manifest include:

```
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "yourscript.js" ]
  }]
```

Of course yourscript.js is if you have one.  I think including it like a file like that is what did it for me if I remember correctly.

Comment: True - but he also didn't say that he didn't! In my case loading JQuery in this way solved the issue for me.

Comment: The question specifically says "popup.html" so it's likely a content_script isn't going to help.